# Using Python to Determine time from Sunset minus 2 hours to 10 pm

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I have a project I'm trying to put into Python, but am not very strong with coding.

I have an array for sunset in local solar time, and want to use that to calculate an hourly load. I am given that the load runs from 2 hours before sunset until 10pm.

I'd like to set up an if statement that says if((sunset - 2) < hour < 22): then x calculation occurs. But it doesn't want to let me do that since sunset is an array.

```
days = np.arange (1, 366) #days to 365
    day_no = np.repeat(days, 24)    
    declination = pv.declination(day_no)
        sunrise, sunset = pv.sun_rise_set(latitude, declination, 0) 

        print('Local Solar Time of Sunrise and Sunset (24h): ', sunrise, sunset)
        for idx,  PV_Ah in enumerate(PV_Array_Ah): 
                day_number = np.floor(idx/24)
                hour = (idx - day_number*24)
            if ((sunset-2) < hour < 22):
                load = (4*3 + 20)*.93
                answer.append(load)
            else:
                load = 0
```

I'll also end up using my 'load' value in a plot, load on the y-axis vs every hour of the year on the x-axis.

How would I go about setting up the if statement for this calculation? And then recording the load in an array to plot?

Comment: How you proceed depends on the details of the variable `sunset`.  For your if statement you will need a scalar and you know that sunset is an array.  You need to explain what's in the array.

Comment: The sunset array gives the time of sunset in military time for every day of the year. (1 - 365, so 366 total points)

Here is what prints out as a sample:
[ 16.75875837  16.75875837  16.75875837 ...,  16.75411855  16.75411855  16.75411855]

Comment: You need an integer variable - call it `i` - representing the day of the year.  The first day is 0, not 1, since Python arrays are zero-referenced.  Then `sunset[i]` is the value for the sunset on that day of the year.  If you don't need the other capabilities of numpy you can easily do this in Python, which will handle lists much long than 365 elements without breaking a sweat.